# combining audio+image to video file with -r result with few more seconds of silent

Tags: audio, video

i am trying to combining audio file with image to mp4 with this line:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.jpg -i audio.aac -c:a copy -vf scale=nhd -shortest test.mp4
```

Everything is perfect. However, when i try to use -r 1 to set frame rate it result with video file with 4 more seconds at the end of silent. Does someone knows what my problem is?

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -r 1 -i image.jpg -i audio.aac -c:a copy -vf scale=nhd -shortest test.mp4
```

Full console command:
https://pastebin.com/5U1BN5tJ

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please [**edit your question**](https://superuser.com/posts/1323012/edit) to include the full, uncut console output from your `ffmpeg` commands. Also, why do you want to set a frame rate, out of curiosity?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. First i only started using FFmpeg a few days ago so are referring to the -report command? if so here is the full console:
https://pastebin.com/5U1BN5tJ

Second, the reason i want to use the -r 1 is because this video is just an image and i know it will make the whole process quicker.

Comment: and by the way, I find this problem occur also when i let ffmpeg re encoding the audio and not using -c:a copy.